# Why MySQL inner join can not find column after as

Tags: mysql

```
select appsflyer_device_id as idd,media_source from PlayerAppData inner join
(select APID from PlayerRecharge) as t1
on t1.APID = idd;
```

errr: Unknown column 'idd' in 'on clause'

Comment: Because you can not use aliasses at this point

Answer (score 0):

You could not use same alias at SELECT clause and ON clause. You should try

```
SELECT appsflyer_device_id AS idd, 
       media_source 
FROM   playerappdata p 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT apid 
                   FROM   playerrecharge) AS t1 
               ON t1.apid = p.appsflyer_device_id;
```